# WorkManager OneTimeWorkRequest has a long delay before actual execution

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I'll put the code first then I'll explain what's happening:

```
 Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();

    Data data = new Data.Builder()
            .putLong(InformationUpdateWorker.INFO_ID, infoId)
            .putInt(InformationUpdateWorker.ID, id)
            .putLong(InformationUpdateWorker.INFO_W_ID, (long)infoWId)
            .putString(InformationUpdateWorker.INFO_L_ID, null)
            .build();

    final OneTimeWorkRequest task = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(InformationUpdateWorker.class)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .setInputData(data)
            .setInitialDelay(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();

    workManager.enqueue(task);
```

So the above task can be run multiple times based on user action. So there can be anywhere between 1-100 (realistically) `OneTimeWorkRequest` that is 'enqueued' within a span of 8 hours. I do  have one constraint which is it requires internet connection.

Also note that I put a `BackoffPolicy` for retries to start at 1 minute then grows linearly.

Now the issue here is that the requests don't seem to get executed right away and when they do (sometimes 2-4 hours before enqueue), all 1-100 requests get executed at the same time so it looks like it got batched. I know that `WorkManager` decides to schedule it at the appropriate time while meeting my constraints, but something seems weird here. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

I'm not sure if the users are actually not experiencing an internet connection, but I tried it myself with firing multiple OneTimeWorkRequests every 5 seconds and they would only execute together after maybe 5 minutes later.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @GeekGuy so I was looking at it all the wrong way. `Android-workmanager` is based on deferred execution, not immediate. Decided to not use this implementation for my use case.

Comment: I have this problem until now, which alternative worked for you?